# Calling an async middleware inside of another async middleware in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

Is it possible to call an async middleware inside of another async middleware in Express.js?

Whenever I try to do so, it doesn't execute in the order I would like it to.

I want them to execute in order and have an output of `First, Second, Third`.

Could anyone explain why or how I can achieve what I'm trying to?

```js
const first = async (req, res, next) => {  
  console.log('First');
  next()
}

const second = async (req, res, next) => {
  await first(req, res, next);
  console.log('Second');
  next();
}

router.get('/logs', second, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Third');
  res.send('Done');
});

// Console Output:
// First
// Third
// Second
```

If I don't execute `first()` inside of `second()` it works just fine, but for something I'm doing I want to be able to execute the middleware inside of the other.

```js
const first = async (req, res, next) => {  
  console.log('First');
  next()
}

const second = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Second');
  next();
}

router.get('/logs', first, second, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Third');
  res.send('Done');
});

// Console Output:
// First
// Second
// Third
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed `next` to the `first` function, which will call the route handler, instead of `second` code

You have to pass a new callback

```
const first = async (req, res, next) => {  
  console.log('First');
  next()
}

const second = async (req, res, next) => {
  await first(req, res, () => {
    console.log('Second');
    next();
  });
}

router.get('/logs', second, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Third');
  res.send('Done');
});
```

or

```
const first = async (req, res, next) => {  
  console.log('First');
  next()
}

const second = async (req, res, next) => {
  await new Promise(r => first(req, res, r))
  console.log('Second');
  next();
}

router.get('/logs', second, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Third');
  res.send('Done');
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, it worked! Thank you, you are incredible. Are you able to go into a bit of a more in-depth explanation as to why you wouldn't pass in `next` to the middleware and add it to your answer? Also, am I able to use `async` for that callback function replacing the `next`?